# Dictionary with key derived from Object value's property?

Tags: c#, collections, redundancy

I want to use a Dictionary to hold a collection of objects, because the most frequent operation is going to be fetching a specific unique entity. These entities already have an ID, so it's natural that I'd want to be able to fetch them using this ID property rather than any other index or identifier. My naive approach is to get each object's ID just before inserting it into the dictionary, and use that value as the key. But is there a better way? I'm keeping this general because I feel it's universal across languages with dictionaries, and I was almost going to ask on Programmers instead, but I'm coming at this from an implementation details perspective as well as a best practices perspective.

- Is there any way (in C#) to make the key a reference to the object's own ID, and if so would there be merit in doing so?
- If the Object ID is read-only, and the key is always taken from each object on insertion, do I still have to worry about the fact that I have data redundancy?
- Is there any way to match the lookup speed of a dictionary while querying against the actual properties of the objects in the collection, thus avoiding the redundancy?
- Would a better means of removing the redundancy be to remove the ID property from the object, and have its dictionary key be its only identifier?
- Am I worrying needlessly about this?

Edit: Just to clarify, this isn't primarily another newbie-doing-premature-optimisation query – I'm more worried about data redundancy, and whether this even counts as data redundancy, and if this is a form of such that people have any opinions on.

Comment: Probably needlessly worrying. How many million objects do you have in your dictionary?

Comment: At least I didn't convince myself I needed a HashSet...

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to write a custom Dictionary class where the key is a `Func<T>`, but I suspect you'd be trading (minimal) speed for (minimal) size..

Comment: BTW, what is your key? If it's a class instance it will be a reference anyway. If it's a string there will be only one copy. If it's an int, long, ... then it's tiny. Also, benchmark against a simple `List<T>`; for small collections it will beat `Dictionary<T>`. (And then go with whichever code is easiest to read and maintain because 99% of the time that's what matters most in the long run.)

Comment: The key is an int, and your last point is my main concern. If the method that adds an element to the dictionary is the sole point of responsibility re: copying object.ID into the key field, is it clear to the user/reader what's going on here? In other words the class doesn't expose the dictionary itself, you add an element via `addThing(MyClass x)` and retrieve it via `getThing(int key)` (whereas if it was a list, I'd be doing `list.First(x => x.ID == inputID)` or something)

Comment: There isn't any redundancy. Having an key to look up your data is necessary. If you could use the object itself then you wouldn't need to look it up. You would effectively have a chicken or the egg problem.

Comment: An int is four bytes, a reference is eight bytes on modern hardware, and you are worried about duplicating the data? Making a duplicate takes up half the memory of taking a reference! And regardless, this is four bytes we're talking about. You could allocate ten million of them without breaking a sweat.

Comment: No you're right about the size, of course, I'm not concerned about that, I'm just concerned about the concept of storing a critical value in two different places, because I've sat through too many database analysis and design lectures and have been conditioned to never do this, in the off chance that the two fields (object.ID and the row key in the dictionary) ended up with different values – but I'm just being pedantic I think. The comment left by @Enigmativity above more or less clarified things for me, I'm more than ready to accept the answer "no, there's no better way of doing this"